# Xcode stuck on "Installing components..."

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode9, macos-high-sierra, xcode9.4

Xcode keeps getting stuck on "Installing components...", it stops at around 40%. I've let it sit for a whole night, reinstalling it from the App Store and searching for solutions on the internet, but all with no succes.

When I Force Quit and restart  Xcode, it does the same thing except that the progress bar immediately jumps to 100% but after that it won't budge. I can only get back to the 40% when i restart my computer.

I have Xcode version 9.4 and i'm running macOS High Sierra (10.13.5).

[Question asked when starting the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMmfI.png)

[Installation stuck at 40%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITtIc.png)

[Installation stuck at 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jteSF.png)

Edit: I've fixed it by deleting some .kext files that were messing things up. Found the following on an Apple Community post:

1. Open Terminal in /Applications/Utilities
2. Enter "system_profiler SPExtensionsDataType > ~/Desktop/kextList.txt" without the quotes and hit return(this will take a while to run).
3. There should now be a kextList.txt file on your desktop, open it and press both the "Apple(Command)" and "F" keys to bring up the find.
4. In the find field insert "Obtained from: Not Signed" Copy the destination to the .kext file to a list for use later.
5. Browse your drive to /System/Library/Extensions and remove any of the unsigned kext files.
6. Reboot and you should be all set.

Comment: I found some helpful information to examine and unload kernel extensions here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57240/how-to-check-what-is-preventing-mbp-from-graceful-shutdown-restart-and-fix-it

In particular, I did the following to remove two kexts that I wasn't using:

sudo kextunload -b com.AmbrosiaWS.AudioSupport
sudo kextunload -b com.google.dfsfuse.filesystems.dfsfuse
(and I prevented Google Drive from launching at startup in the Users & Groups prefs panel).

Comment: You may also get this because of some ongoing pending Software updates. I had to do a Time Machine System Restore and had a iMovie update, that blocked the XCode updated. Seemed to queue it up. You could see a red circle on the System Preferences grey cog. When you clicked on that you could see time remaining. As soon as iMovies updated... XCode update started. (Exhibited by being stuck at 100% for me).

Answer (score 6):

Starting MacOS in Safe Mode and the starting Xcode should fix the issue. I tried in MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 with Xcode version 10.1

Comment: Tried it as well and it worked. Can you accept this answer or did this not solve it for you?

Comment: it is impressive how bad is the whole developer experience with Apple. Everything stinks.